# C# Web API and SQL server global where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

So i'm trying to implement a soft delete feature, and I have a DeletedAt field in almost all of my tables. My problem now is since this feature is not native to `Web API`, I would have to put a where clause of `DeletedAt == null` in all of my queries. My question would be, is there a way to put this where clause globally either in Web API or maybe if it's also possible from SQL Server?

Comment: Are you using EF?

Comment: Yes I am using EF.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are using Entity Framework. You can add a global filter at OnModelCreating event by adding a discriminator like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(m => m.Requires("DeletedAt").HasValue(false));
   modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Map(m => m.Requires("DeletedAt").HasValue(false)); 
}
```

OR

You can use this package: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters

Comment: Yes I am using EF, will try that later.

Comment: Tried your answer. Do I need to update migrations or anything? Cause I get the following error:
`Schema specified is not valid. Errors: error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.DateTime[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member 'DeletedAt' in type 'MyModel' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.bit[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'DeletedAt' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.MyModel'.
`